# Задать значения переменным по цепочке в JS

Tags: javascript

Как можно в JS задать значения переменным по цепочке, вроде

```
var date = date[0] = the_creation_of_information.split('., ');
```

Насколько знаю, в PHP так можно, а в JS?

Comment: У вас не получилось проверить?

Comment: а какой результат от этого ожидается?

Comment: Вытащить из "1887-1888 гг., Италия" дату.

Comment: какую? 1887 или 1888 или обе?

Comment: Обе, "1887-1888 гг".

Comment: тогда не понятен смысл `date = date[0]` в коде. Что в итоге должно оказаться в переменно `date`?

Comment: Да, уже убрал :) Вначале стал записывать в date, потом уже использовать date[0]; Жаль, не удается это сделать в одну строку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46340/discussion-between-grundy-and-timur-musharapov).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ES2015 даже нет нужны в индексаторе. Можно использовать [деструктурирующее присваивание](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
var [date] = "1887-1888 гг., Италия".split('., ');
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 3):

Оператор '=' в JS работает справа налево.

То есть ваша запись эквивалентна следующему:

```
var date
date[0] = the_creation_of_information.split('., ');
date = date[0]
```

что вызовет ошибку, так как на второй строчке date = undefined, и следовательно у date нет свойства date[0].

Comment: То есть в 1 такой операцией сделать подобное невозможно?

Answer (score 2):

Вы не можете присвоить переменной `date` массив и его нулевой элемент одновременно. Но вам и не надо никуда присваивать массив!

Оператор индексирования (`[]`) работает с любыми выражениями, а не только с переменными.

```
var date = the_creation_of_information.split('., ')[0];
```